# One-sided derivative in $a$ of a continuous monotone function whose derivative on $(a,b]$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Consider a function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $f$ is continuous and monotone on $[a,b]$,
- $f'$ is bounded on $(a,b]$.

Does $f$ have a right derivative in $a$, i.e. does the limit $\lim_{x \downarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exist?

What if assume in addition that $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b]$?

Counterexample if $f'$ is not bounded: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Construct a monotone function with the required properties which satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/2^n)=1/2^n$ if $n$ is even and $f(1/2^n)=2/2^n$ if $n$ is odd,
that is, $f(1/2^{2n})=f(1/2^{2n+1})=1/2^{2n}$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess it would look something like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/00psyi0ef2

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is known as the Devil's Staircase. The function is monotone and continuous on $[0,1]$, but is not differentiable at any point in the Cantor set (including failing to have a right derivative at zero). Suprisingly the function is differentiable everywhere outside the Cantor set, hence, we say the function has "derivative zero almost everywhere".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Cantor function is very peculiar. However, I was hoping for a function whose derivative exists on $(a,b]$.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad, I did not realize you wanted differentiable on the whole interval.